# I Bring 1 kg of Iron to a Flux Density of 1 T. How Much Energy Does That Take?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

I'm an EE, not a physicist, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

I learned a bit of magnetics when I took motors 20 years ago, but I don't remember much.

I'm reaching out to the physics community because finding EE's who know the answer to this question can be tough. (Take me, for example.)

I bring 1 kg of iron to a flux density of 1 T. How much energy does that take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we can answer questions like this using $ \frac{U}{V} = \frac{B^2}{2 \mu} $ (magnetic energy stored per unit volume), but since iron is nonlinear and ferromagnetic, we need to use its magnetisation curve.

[image]

In this case $ \frac{U}{V} = \int_{0}^{B} H \ dB $, so the energy required per unit volume of iron is equal to the area between this curve, the vertical axis, and the line $ B = 1 $. It's quite linear in this region so you could approximate it as a triangle (which is equivalent to just using the original formula above). I estimate it as

$$ \text{energy per unit volume} = \frac{1}{2} \times {1} \times {2000} = 1000 J = 1 \ kJ. $$

Perhaps [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nde-ed.org%2FPhysics%2FMagnetism%2FHysteresisLoop.xhtml&psig=AOvVaw24Yud5eyYU9-Z2oT3M7pq4&ust=1695849518375000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CA8QjRxqFwoTCNCIx_KZyYEDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE) diagram looks familiar - we are looking at the dashed part of the curve (initial charging up) in this analysis.